# Using 'vwcol' multiple times separately

Tags: align, minipage, multicolumn

I am trying to use `vwcol` multiple times separately, but it does not give the desired result. Any idea how to solve it? Or maybe suggestions for a different package? Hereby a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{my_cv}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[a4paper, total={7in, 11in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor, enumitem, multicol, hyperref, vwcol}

\definecolor{darkmidnightblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.2, 0.4}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\def\columnseprulecolor{\color{darkmidnightblue}}
\setlength{\columnsep}{.5cm}

\hypersetup{colorlinks, urlcolor=darkmidnightblue}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%\pagecolor{lightgray}

\name{\color{darkmidnightblue} \textbf{-}
\vspace{.3em}
\name{\color{darkmidnightblue} \large \textit{Curriculum Vitae}}
\vspace{.5em}

\section*{\color{darkmidnightblue} Personal data}
\begin{description}[itemsep=0em, align=left, labelwidth=1.55in]
\item [Date of birth] -
\item [Address] -
\item [E-mail] -
\item [Mobile] -
\end{description}

\section*{\color{darkmidnightblue} Education}

\begin{vwcol}[widths={0.23, 0.5}, sep=.5cm, rule=1pt, postrule, indent=0em, rulecolor=darkmidnightblue, justify=flush]
\textsc{Sep 2018 -- Dec 2018}
\subsection{-} \vspace{-.8em}
\subsubsection{-} \vspace{-.8em}
-
\end{vwcol} 

\begin{vwcol}
...
\end{vwcol}
\end{document}
```

Class file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{my_cv}[2019/08/11 My custom CV class]
\LoadClass{article}


\newcommand{\name}[1]{%
  \leftline{\Large{#1}}
}

\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section} % Customise the \section command 
  {\large\bfseries\scshape\raggedright} % Make the \section headers large (\Large)
    {}{0em}
  {}
  [\color{darkmidnightblue}\bfseries\titlerule] % Inserts a horizontal line after the heading

\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\large\bfseries\scshape\raggedright}
  {}{0em}
  {}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\large\scshape\raggedright}
  {}{0em}
  {}

\newcommand{\datedsection}[2]{%
  \section[#1]{#1 \hfill #2}%
}
\newcommand{\datedsubsection}[2]{%
  \subsection[#1]{#1 \hfill #2}%
}
```

[image: current result]

Comment: how should we know what your `my_cv.cls` is doing? Btw: the options should go before the class name argument, no after it.

Comment: my_cv.cls is almost identical to article.cls

Comment: then why don't you replace it with article in your example?

Comment: no one can run this code as posted, please post an example that shows the problem.

Comment: Your example document is not compilable due to undefined commands such as `\name`. Please include the necessary `\usepackage` commands or definitions in yur example.

Comment: Please also describe or show a sketch of the desired output.

Comment: Lastly, it looks like you've got two separate accounts, (See https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/160881/sean  and the very similar questions: [Dates and text alignment in custom CV](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503877/134144)  and [Dates and text alignment in a CV](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503864/134144). (The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: From the `vwcol` package manual: "This package provides an environment that allows paragraph text to be typesetinto multiple columns of uneven width, with text that flows from one column tothe next."  From this description, I don't think this package is suitable in your case. I'd recommend to either use a `description` environment or a `tabular`/`longtabular`/`tabularx`/`xltabular` instead.